# Changing svg by using setting attribute returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I try to implement the effect of changing svg images by using jQuery. My code works in the browser but it returns error in the console. I want to remove the error. What should I do?

Error

```
(unknown) Uncaught TypeError: a[b].target.className.indexOf is not a function
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var ScrollTop = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
        if(ScrollTop > 150) {
            $(".outer-wrapper").css("border-bottom","1px solid #cdc8c7");
            $(".svg--logo").find("use").attr("xlink:href", "#billie-logo-sml");
        } else {
            $(".outer-wrapper").css("border-bottom","");
            $(".svg--logo").find("use").attr("xlink:href", "#billie-logo");
        }
    })
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="header-item">
<a class="logo" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">
  <svg class="svg--logo">
    <title>Billie Logo</title>
    <use xlink:href="#billie-logo"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use CSS `background-image` as there is some issue between SVG and HTML/JavaScript. It works fine. I will show part of my code.

Javascript

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = Math.round(window.pageYOffset); // window.scrollY won't work in IE9+
    var elm = document.getElementById("logo");
    if(scrollTop > 30) {
        $(".outer-wrapper").css("border-bottom","1px solid #cdc8c7");
        $(".svg--logo").addClass('small');
        $(".svg--logo").removeClass('large');
    } else {
        $(".outer-wrapper").css("border-bottom","");
        $(".svg--logo").removeClass('small');
        $(".svg--logo").addClass('large');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.large {
  background-image: url(../../../assets/images/illus/billie_logo_large.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -60px;
  margin-left: -90px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.small {
  background-image: url(../../../assets/images/illus/billie_logo_small.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use jQuery here. jQuery assumes all elements to be HTML and to have interfaces accordingly. But while in HTML the `Element.className` interface is a string, in SVG the interface `SVGElement.className` is a SVGAnimatedString (which is an Object with properties baseVal and animVal).

The error is not in your code, but inside the inner workings of jQuery. I can't even tell you exactly where it is, because there is no obvious reason why jQuery would need to find out the position of a character inside the class attribute - that is what the error message seems to be about.

I can't see a good reason why you would need to use jQuery at all. Using SVG means Internet Explorer 8 isn't supported anyway, and that means you can use plain Javascript without breaking anything:

```
document.addEventListener("load", function() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        var ScrollTop = Math.round(window.pageYOffset); // window.scrollY won't work in IE9+
        if(ScrollTop > 150) {
            document.querySelector(".outer-wrapper").style["border-bottom"] = "1px solid #cdc8c7";
            document.querySelector(".svg--logo use").setAttribute("xlink:href", "#billie-logo-sml");
        } else {
            document.querySelector(".outer-wrapper").style["border-bottom"] = "";
            document.querySelector(".svg--logo use").setAttribute("xlink:href", "#billie-logo");
        }
    });
});
```

Note that `Element.querySelector` only finds the first matching element. If there are multiple elements, you need to use `Element.querySelectorAll` and loop over the resulting Iterable.

Comment: also this error only shown in google chrome. error does not show up in safari and firefox.

Comment: Are you sure the error is raised by this event routine? Check the calls stack closely.

Comment: Yes. it's sure. When I commented out  `document.querySelector("use").setAttribute("xlink:href", "#billie-logo-sml");` , no error comes up in the console.

Comment: And what does the call stack say?

Comment: it shows `Error
    at (index):373` I use jekyll and files are compiled to `index.html`.

Comment: Surely that is not all? You'll need to find out where the call `a[b].target.className.indexOf` comes from and what are the calling functions. The link in the right column of the error message should be able to take you to the right source.

Comment: The link in the right column points out `u.zi=function(a,b,c){c.ah();this.B?this.Qh(a):this.Ph(a);c.f.G()};u.sg=function(){this.C=!1;this.H=0;dm(this.s,this.f)};u.rg=function(a){a.target==window&&(this.C=!0,this.H=0,dm(this.s,.01))};u.ti=function(a){if(this.b&&this.h){for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++)if(a[b].target&&a[b].target.className&&(0<=a[b].target.className.indexOf(bc)||0==a[b].target.className.indexOf("goog-")))return;this.pa.add(C(this.rj,this))}};u.rj=function(){this.B=!0;this.I.stop();this.I=du(this);return!1};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163200/discussion-between-ccprog-and-aaayumi).